# What content type use for Modern Page on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-pages

Any one have idea about What type of content type use for Modern Page on SP 365?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The content type used for the Modern Pages:

- Name: "**Site Page**"
- ID: 0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118
- The content type is using these columns:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to site settings -> Site Content Types under Web Designer Galleries -> Site Page under Document Content Types.

Hope these articles are helpful to you:

[Modern page content types](https://joannecklein.com/2018/07/14/modern-page-content-types/)

[Create a custom content type for modern pages](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/create-a-custom-content-type-for-our-modern-pages-am-i-doing/m-p/286286)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I used these below content types for the Modern site page which helps me to translate my modern page into a different language.